# How is close set condition used in this proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am reading mathematical statistics by ShaoJun (P56 theorem 1.9). Does anyone know that how close-set works in this proof? I don't know why the close-set condition is needed in this theorem. And I cannot see where we use the close-set condition in proof a→b.

Let $X,X_1,X_2...$ be random k-vectors. $X_n\to X$ is equivalent to any one of the following conditions:

(a).$E[h(X_n)]\to E[h(X)]$ for every bounded continuous conditions;

(b).$\limsup_nP_{X_n}(C)≤P_{X}(C)$ for any closed set $C\subset R^k$.

Proof:

To show (a) implies (b).

Let $C$ be a closed set and $f_C(x)=\inf\{∥x−y∥:y∈C\}$. Then $f_C$ is continuous. For $j=1,2,...,$ define $\phi(t)=I_{(−∞,0]}+(1−jt)I_{(0,j−1]}$. Then $h_j(x)=\phi_j(f_C(x))$ is continuous and bounded,$h_j≥h_{j+1},j=1,2,...$ and $h_j→I_C(x)$ as $j\to\infty$. Hence $\limsup_nP_{Xn}(C)\le\lim_{n\to\infty}E[h_j(X_n)]=E[h_j(X)]$ for each $j$ (by (a)). By the dominated convergence theory, $E[h_j(X_n)]→E[I_C(X)]=P_X(C)$. This proves (b).

Comment: Do you mean a "closed-set condition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the function
$$
\varphi_j(t)=1_{(-\infty,0]}(t)+(1-jt)1_{(0,j^{-1}]}(t)
$$
is a continuous approximation of the indicator $\varphi(t)=1_{(-\infty,0]}(t)$, and $\varphi_j(t)\to \varphi(t)$ as $j\to\infty$. Second, since $C$ is a closed set, $\varphi_j(f_C(x))\to 1_C(x)$ pointwise as $j\to\infty$, which allows one to use the dominated convergence theorem.

---

When $C$ is not a closed set, the convergence of $\varphi_j(f_C(x))$ to $1_C(x)$ need not hold. Take $x\in \operatorname{cl}(C)\cap C^c$. Since $d(x,C)=0$, $\varphi_j(f_C(x))=1$ for all $j$, but $1_C(x)=0$.